# How can I sync the complete `local_dir` (`~/ray_results`) with the head node?

Tags: ray, ray-tune

I am creating custom result files in my jobs and want to sync them from the worker nodes to the head nodes (To rsync them down to my local computer later on). I tried to write them all into the `local_dir` e.g. `~./ray_results` but unfortunately it seems that ray tune is only synching the individual trial folders in the `local_dir`. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; try writing them to the `self.logdir` for each trainable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a way to get the logdir also when using the Function-based API?

Comment: tune.get_trial_dir() is the new API

Comment: Thanks for following up on this.